# using an enumerable built-in Ruby to access and manipulate nested data

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

Is there a built-in which will easily allow you to access the objects within an array and its sub arrays so that one can achieve something along the lines of:

```
array = [5, 10, [15, 20], 25, [30, 35, 40]
array#method { #block that adds 5} => [10, 15, [20, 25], 30, [35, 40, 45]
```

I'm unconcerned if it is destructive or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a recursive lambda:

```
add_five = lambda { |e| e.is_a?(Enumerable) ? e.map(&add_five) : e + 5 }
new_array = array.map(&add_five)
```

Adjust the `e.is_a?(Enumerable)` test to match your situation, `e.is_a?(Array)` would be tighter but possibly unnecessarily so.

Comment: There's also the `responds_to?(:map)` approach where if it smells duck-like enough you may as well ask it to quack.